# Any tips for switching from CakePHP to Ruby on Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, cakephp, switch-statement

I've been wanting to make the switch from PHP. Anyone care to highlight the similar classes or the key differences between CakePHP and Ruby on Rails?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im a rails developer that took on a PHP client last year and after researching available php frameworks I decided on CakePHP because I felt it was the most Rails-esque and stable.

So I was in the opposite position that you find yourself now. Quite honestly I have never regretted my decision to start learning rails and im sure you will find the task even easier coming from a CakePHP background.

My advice to you should dive right in, take a couple hours tonight, whip up a quick demo project like a blog or todo list in rails, read through some tutorials. My guess is that you will find right at home. Similar project directory structure, similar database schema, similar conventions. CakePHP comes very very close to cloning the core rails way of doing things.

Comment: I think you might've just motivated ME to try something new!  I may try to whip up the same blog app as CakeBook has in RoR just to give it a whirl.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I'll definately give Rails a go again. Last year I tried Rails but aborted a project as I couldn't get things done the Rails way. I wasn't good in Ruby and everything was just too much for me in the short time frame.

Answer (score 6):

**Learn Ruby first.** You won't get Rails if you try to make it do things the PHP way. Ruby is a beautiful language and makes you think differently about a lot of things.

Out of all the Ruby tutorials out there, [Why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) is by *far* the best one out there, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the Ruby tutorial. ;)